# Is there an easy way I can open a data set of h5 files in R?

Tags: r, hdf5

I recently downloaded a [subset](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/getting-dataset#subset) of the Million Song Data-set to use for some research. The collection of 10,000 observations is stored as 10,000 .h5 files, and I was wondering if there was a way to open and convert the data to a format that I could work with in R. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should Google for a library to read HDF files.

It's a fairly standard format, I bet there is a module.